# Why does for readelements() fro loop not print out?

Tags: java

So I've been stuck trying to get my array list to print out in the right order but it keeps printing the original input i inserted backwards for some reason, i've tried reading the array in reverse order but it doesn't work either.

```
public static void Add()
{
    System.out.println("You may now enter your virtual diary entry...");
    System.out.println("You may END the program at any time by typing in endp...\n");
    boolean loop = true; 
    while(loop)
    {
        String Stop = Cons.nextLine();

        if (Stop.equals("endp")| Stop.equals(""))
        {
            readelements();
            break;  
        } else {
            for (int i =0 ; i <= Notes.size(); ) {

                Notes.add(i, Stop); 
                i++;
                break; 
            }
        }
    }
} 

public static void readelements()

{

    if (Empty()) {

        Empty();
    }
    for(int i =0; i < Notes.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println(i + " = " + Notes.get(i).toString());
        Notes.toString();
    }   
}
```

Comment: Can you explain better what your program has to do? Can you show us the `Notes` class and the `Empty` method?

Comment: Please provide more details, clarify your question and add [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

In your else block, you break after one iteration (when i = 0) so you're always running Notes.add(0, Stop). This prepends Stop to Notes, so Notes will be in reverse order. Removing the break will cause you to insert duplicate elements into Notes (note that you're looping but always inserting Stop). Try changing your entire else block to just `Notes.add(Stop);`. This will add the current value of Stop to the end of Notes and should fix your problem.

Comment: Thank you for the answer this ended up being the issue!! The purpose of this program is to create a virtual diary that allows a user to store notes in. i am still working on other sections of the program such as removing previous notes made and also searching for notes and editing notes. so this answer has definitely helped me get back on track!!